My "sticky" doesn't work when it finds a container
when I scroll until the vision mission section the sticky doesn't work.
I need help, the body has more containers too.
I tried different positions and I couldn't make that works. I don't know how can I fix it :(
All containers are inside the body


header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #cfbbc0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  padding: 0 17rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.visionymision {
  margin: 60px 0;
  background-color: #cfbbc0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
<div class="banner"></div>

<header>
  <div class="container">
    <figure class="logo">
      <a href="#inicio">
        <img src="/imagenes/Texto del párrafo (1).png" alt="logo" />
      </a>
    </figure>
    <nav>
      <li><a href="#quiensoy">¿Quién soy?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#clases">Clases</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contacto">Contacto</a></li>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="visionymision">
  <img src="imagenes/Euge-347.png" alt="" />
  <div class="textov">
    <p>lorem</p>
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
</div>



